Why doesn't the flute fingering for high G require an open hole to "vent"?
I have a wonder about how flute fingerings work.  Why is it that the fingerings for high E, F, and F# require a hole in the middle of the instrument to be opened, but not high G?
I've guessed so far that opening the third finger of the left hand for high E, and the second finger for the high F/F#, creates an acoustic node that makes it easy to double the frequency.  We are basically fingering the lower octave note, creating a node by "venting" one hole roughly halfway between the tone hole and the first open hole at the "end" of the fingering.  But high G seems to work just fine without this need?  What's going on here?
To further confuse me, the fingering for the next 2 notes (G# and A) continues the "venting" technique. I added red lines to show the vents.  Please instruct me, O Stack Exchange!

Image Source

High E can be played as the fourth harmonic of low E. Opening a hole as vent a quarter of the length of the tube for low E improves the quality of the harmonic, that would mean opening the G hole (controlled by the LH3 G# key). Unfortunately the higher harmonics become successively flatter due to the affect of the tube below the lowest open hole, so the pitch is improved by venting the note a bit shorter, in this case using the LH3 G# hole instead of G, a least on a flute with E-mechanism.
Going from E to F means closing the G#-hole and opening the A-hole.
Going from F to F# means opening the next hole (Bb). Unfortunately the A-holes stays open which makes F# a bit problematic. Some flutes have a high F#-mechanism to compensate for this.
The fingering for high G simply continues the system. Going from F# to G you close the Bb and A holes with LH2 and open the next hole up: the B hole with the LH thumb.
Going from G to G# continues the system: the C hole is opened as a vent (LH1). The thumb B-hole is left open, but it could be closed without affecting the note too much.
High A is different, it's played as the fifth harmonic of F, so you would want vent the tube at about a fifth of the length. This would be around the G-hole, but because of the flatness of the harmonics both LH3 G and G#-holes are used. The LH1 C-hole can also be used as a vent. The standard fingering uses both together.

My misunderstanding was not realizing that the left thumb isn't used for high G.  Thank you for the info!
